# Find constant subarrays in large numpy array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have a numpy float array like

```
v = np.array([1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,...])
```

I would need to identify all the constant segments in the array like

```
[{value:1.0,location:0,duration:2},..]
```

Efficiency is the main metric

Comment: Cool.  You can start by using `np.diff()` and looking at the places where the diff is 0 (or nearly 0, perhaps).  Let us know when you have written some code if you need help with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def island_props(v):
    # Get one-off shifted slices and then compare element-wise, to give
    # us a mask of start and start positions for each island.
    # Also, get the corresponding indices.
    mask = np.concatenate(( [True], v[1:] != v[:-1], [True] ))
    loc0 = np.flatnonzero(mask)

    # Get the start locations
    loc = loc0[:-1]

    # The values would be input array indexe by the start locations.
    # The lengths woul be the differentiation between start and stop indices.
    return v[loc], loc, np.diff(loc0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: v
Out[143]: array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  5.,  2.])

In [144]: value, location, lengths = island_props(v)

In [145]: value
Out[145]: array([ 1.,  2.,  5.,  2.])

In [146]: location
Out[146]: array([0, 2, 6, 7])

In [147]: lengths
Out[147]: array([2, 4, 1, 1])
```

**Runtime test**

Other approaches -

```
import itertools
def MSeifert(a):
    return [{'value': k, 'duration': len(list(v))} for k, v in 
             itertools.groupby(a.tolist())]

def Kasramvd(a):
    return np.split(v, np.where(np.diff(v) != 0)[0] + 1)
```

Timings -

```
In [156]: v0 = np.array([1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,5.0,2.0])

In [157]: v = np.tile(v0,10000)

In [158]: %timeit MSeifert(v)
     ...: %timeit Kasramvd(v)
     ...: %timeit island_props(v)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 44.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 36.1 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 140 µs per loop
```

Comment: I am trying to extend this to 2 dimensions and I am finding it exceedingly hard. Could you take a crack at it? Essentially the same requirement except add one dimension like in an image. Even though 2d still interested in vertical direction only for island props (like running the above function in a for loop along vertical slices of a 2d array). The main trouble comes when dealing with uneven array lengths when doing np.diff in 2d. Help!

Answer (score 2):

You can group the equal items as following then simply do the rest by getting the size of the array, first element and the index:

```
In [2]: v = np.array([1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0])

In [4]: np.split(v, np.where(np.diff(v) != 0)[0] + 1)
Out[4]: 
[array([ 1.,  1.]),
 array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]),
 array([ 3.,  3.]),
 array([ 5.]),
 array([ 6.,  6.,  6.])]
```

The equation `np.diff(v) != 0` denotes the places of where the sequence changes (the difference is not 0) and `np.where()` gives you the respective indices of those places (from the boolean result). Then you can simply split the array using `np.split()`.

And finally you can use a list comprehension to get the desire result:

```
In [7]: locations = np.where(np.diff(v) != 0)[0] + 1

In [8]: result = np.split(v, locations)

In [9]: [{'value':arr[0], 'location':loc, 'duration':arr.size} for loc, arr in zip(locations, result)]
Out[9]: 
[{'duration': 2, 'value': 1.0, 'location': 2},
 {'duration': 4, 'value': 2.0, 'location': 6},
 {'duration': 2, 'value': 3.0, 'location': 8},
 {'duration': 1, 'value': 5.0, 'location': 9}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), it could be a bit slower (haven't timed it) but probably a lot easier to understand:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import itertools
>>> a = np.array([1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0])
>>> [{'value': k, 'duration': len(list(v))} for k, v in itertools.groupby(a.tolist())]
[{'duration': 2, 'value': 1.0}, {'duration': 4, 'value': 2.0}]
```

Comment: that's interesting. Would it be possible to check for another condition than equality using groupy?

Comment: @Sabor `groupby` only checks for equality, but it also accepts a `key` function, so you _can_ do more than element-equality tests. However, that's getting non-trivial (and probably also slow) very fast. Depends on your use-case though.